# cross-compile of Python's greenlet and gevent on Linux x86_64 for PowerPC

Tags: python, linux, cross-compiling, gevent, greenlets

On my Linux x86_64 host, I am trying to cross-compile some additional Python modules for my PowerPC target, specifically, [greenlet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet), [gevent](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent), and [gevent-websockets](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent-websocket/).  Currently, I am stuck just trying to cross-build the greenlet module.

Using info from this site:

http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html

I was able to cross-compile Python 2.7.2 using this setup for my build environment

```
# Undo variables for cross-compile environment
unset ROOT
unset SDKDIR
unset KLIBDIR
unset NFSDIR
unset CONFIG
unset CONFIGURED
unset ARCH
unset OS
unset TOOLCHAIN_BASE
unset TOOLCHAIN_BIN
unset CROSS_COMPILE
unset c
unset KERNEL_DIR
unset AS
unset LD
unset CC
unset AR
unset STRIP
unset SSTRIP
unset OBJCOPY
unset OBJDUMP
unset MAKE
unset CFLAGS

# Set cross-compile variables:
export TOOLCHAIN=/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.3.74-eglibc-2.8.74-dp-2/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-
export CC=${TOOLCHAIN}gcc
export CXX=${TOOLCHAIN}g++
export AR=${TOOLCHAIN}ar
export RANLIB=${TOOLCHAIN}ranlib
export BLDSHARED="${TOOLCHAIN}gcc -shared"
export LDSHARED="${TOOLCHAIN}gcc -shared"
export RFS="../../ltib/rootfs"
export CFLAGS="-save-temps -Wall -I${RFS}/usr/include -I${RFS}/include/python2.7 -L${RFS}/usr/lib -L${RFS}/lib"
export LDFLAGS="-I${RFS}/usr/include -I${RFS}/include/python2.7 -L${RFS}/usr/lib -L${RFS}/lib"
export CROSS_COMPILE=ppc-linux
export CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes
export HOSTARCH=ppc-linux
export BUILDARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Configuring my environment with the above script and then trying to build the greenlet module yields:

```
$ python ./setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'greenlet' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.3.74-eglibc-2.8.74-dp-2/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-gcc -I../../../ltib/rootfs/usr/include -L../../../ltib/rootfs/usr/lib -L../../../ltib/rootfs/lib -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.o
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from greenlet.h:8,
                 from greenlet.c:5:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:849:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
error: command '/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.3.74-eglibc-2.8.74-dp-2/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Why is setup.py pulling from `/usr/include/python2.7` on my host system?  I can't find that dir on my target.  How can I create it for my target?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Trevor

## UPDATE #1:

My relative references to my host's copy of the target's rootfs were incorrect.  Correcting it and rerunning yields:

```
$ python ./setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'greenlet' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.3.74-eglibc-2.8.74-dp-2/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-gcc -save-temps -Wall -I../../ltib/rootfs/usr/include -I../../ltib/rootfs/include/python2.7 -L../../ltib/rootfs/usr/lib -L../../ltib/rootfs/lib -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.o
greenlet.s: Assembler messages:
greenlet.s:832: Error: syntax error; found `(' but expected `,'
greenlet.s:832: Error: junk at end of line: `(31),1'
error: command '/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.3.74-eglibc-2.8.74-dp-2/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

At least it is finding more of my target's include libraries, but now I am really stumped!  :(

Any more suggestions?

Thanks!

## UPDATE #2:

By adding the `-save-temps` flag to the compiler (updated error above), I was able to save and examine the intermediate assembler code that was mentioned in the above error message.  The broken lines are:

```
#APP
 # 52 "platform/switch_ppc_linux.h" 1
    mr 8(31), 1
 # 0 "" 2
```

The MR (move register) op is fairly simple, accepting only 2 args (`mr to-reg, from-reg`).  I don't know how the parenthesis with additional register number were added.  FWIW, here is the referenced macro in the above header file:

```
#define STACK_REFPLUS 1

#ifdef SLP_EVAL

#define STACK_MAGIC 3

/* !!!!WARNING!!!! need to add "r31" in the next line if this header file
 * is meant to be compiled non-dynamically!
 */
#define REGS_TO_SAVE "r13", "r14", "r15", "r16", "r17", "r18", "r19", "r20", \
       "r21", "r22", "r23", "r24", "r25", "r26", "r27", "r28", "r29", \
       "cr2", "cr3", "cr4"
static int
slp_switch(void)
{
    register int *stackref, stsizediff;
    __asm__ volatile ("" : : : REGS_TO_SAVE);
    __asm__ ("mr %0, 1" : "=g" (stackref) : );
    {
        SLP_SAVE_STATE(stackref, stsizediff);
        __asm__ volatile (
            "mr 11, %0\n"
            "add 1, 1, 11\n"
            "add 30, 30, 11\n"
            : /* no outputs */
            : "g" (stsizediff)
            : "11"
            );
        SLP_RESTORE_STATE();
    }
    __asm__ volatile ("" : : : REGS_TO_SAVE);
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

I am starting to wonder if this is a bug in the compiler, because the macro seems simple enough!  Any suggestions? ... Thanks!

Comment: Given that the comments on that blog post seem to imply that people haven't even gotten the target Python to import the standard-library modules, it's not too surprising that the instructions don't work for third-party modules either…

Comment: Not that that's the issue (an issue with the title?), and I might be missing something, but haven't you specified a PPC rather than an ARM toolchain?

Comment: @TiloWiklund: Good catch. The blog he's copied from is about cross-compiling for both ARM and PPC, and he seems to have copied the wrong one. That doesn't actually explain his problems, because the exact same thing would happen if he'd used the ARM toolchain instead. But this implies that he hasn't tried to even minimally test his built Python before moving on to trying to build extensions for it.

Comment: @TiloWiklund:  Thanks, that was a typo.  It was indeed PPC.

Comment: @abarnet:  I already have cross-compile of Python 2.7.2 working, per my original questions.  Please excuse my typo.

Comment: Many projects aren't tested with cross-compilers, so it's plausible that greenlet is detecting that x86_64 and using the wrong inline assembly, which is obviously not going to work. You could get it to save the .s files and look at them to see if they're a mix of x86_64 and PPC. However, I'm still not sure you got the basic setup right, because I think it should be creating build/linux-ppc-2.7, not build/linux-x86_64-2.7. Maybe you should first try to build a C extension that's known to work with cross-compiling, and make sure you can do that, and then come back to greenlet?

Comment: @abarnert: If you look at the above update, you can see that I'm already saving, examining, and reporting the *.s assembly file's content. Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should have asked a new question, because there really are (at least) two completely independent problems here. But, looking at your second problem:

```
__asm__ ("mr %0, 1" : "=g" (stackref) : );
```

This is wrong. I'll explain why below, but first, the following change will likely fix it:

```
__asm__ ("mr %0, 1" : "=r" (stackref) : );
```

You may also need to change the `"g" (stsizediff)` below to `"r" (stsizediff)`.

So, what's wrong with the existing version? First, look at how stackref is defined:

```
register int *stackref, stsizediff;
```

The `register` is a hint to the compiler, saying you think it might make things faster or better if it allocated a register for `stackref` instead of using a stack location, not a requirement. If `stackref` ends up in R12, great; if it ends up 8 bytes into the stack frame, that's fine too. Either is perfectly legal, as long as it doesn't violate any constraints.

So, what constraints are there on `stackref`? The only one is in that asm block quoted above. You've got `"=g" (stackref)` as an output operand. The `=` means it's a write-only constraint, and the `g` means it must be in a register, memory location, or immediate value.

So the compiler's not doing anything wrong. It allocates `stackref` 8 bytes off the stack, which matches the constraint (that's a memory location), then it substitutes that value in for the `"%0"`, and you get:

```
mr 8(31), 1
```

Nothing wrong with that—until you try to assemble it, and the assembler notices that you're trying to use 8(31) with an opcode that only takes registers. But the problem isn't the compiler, or the assembler, it's the code. You asked it to use `stackref` as an operand for `mr`, and didn't force `stackref` to be a register, so you got what you asked for.

Anyway, changing the `"=g"` to `"=r"` changes the constraint from "any register, memory location, or immediate value" to "any general register". That means the compiler has to put `stackref` in a general register. Or, if it can't for some reason, it will fail and tell you why, instead of generating assembly that won't assemble.

So, why did this work for the original author? Well, he probably got lucky, and `stackref` got allocated to, say, R12, instead of 8 bytes into the stack frame, so he ended up with `mr 12, 1`, which assembles just fine.

Or, one more possibility. Looking at the git tree, it looks like the code was developed on Mac OS X, then ported to AIX (by people who are primarily Mac developers) a decade ago, then copied verbatim from AIX to linux (even leaving the description "Port for AIX on PowerPC"), and not touched significantly since. Both OS X and AIX only had gcc 3 back then. So, maybe that's the reason it worked for everyone at the time, and isn't working for you. And maybe just getting an older cross-compiler will solve your problem. But I'd try fixing the code first.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.  Incidentally, if I forced the `-O2` compiler optimization, the compiler would assemble correctly.  FWIW, I received similar, supportive information from the module's authors here:  [link](https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/16) ... Thanks for the expert, detailed, and clear explanation.  I know it took some time, and I greatly appreciate it.  :)

Comment: I can believe that -O2 causes it to allocate stackref in a register while -O0 leaves it on the stack. But it's not really a fix just because it happens to work on your machine, any more than the original code was correct because it happens to work on the original coder's machine… Anyway, hopefully you can get them to accept the =r fix upstream (and get it tested, of course, rather than going by my recollection of gcc inline assembly…).

Answer (score 1):

> Why is setup.py pulling from /usr/include/python2.7 on my host system?

It's not. The `/usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:849` refers to the source used to build your host Python, which may or may not actually be on your system.

> I can't find that dir on my target. How can I create it for my target?

I'm not sure you want to. I think you're off on a red herring.

Here's the key to your problem:

```
$ python ./setup.py build
```

You're using your host's native Python to build an extension, and you're not doing anything to tell it you want the extension cross-compiled. So, as far as it knows, you're trying to build greenlet for it, not for the other Python. Hence things like this:

> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

But of course you're giving it the ARM cross-compiler, which isn't going to be able to compile extensions for your x86_64 host python, hence this:

> /usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:849:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."

Your host Python was built with LONG_BIT set for a 64-bit LP system, but it's trying to build code with a compiler for a 32-bit system.

The blog post http://kynesim.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/cross-compiling-python-for-arm-with.html (linked from the one you cited) shows how to build third-party C extension modules. As you can see, it's not entirely trivial, and may need a bit of experimentation to get it to work, but it looks like it's doable.

Comment: How would I tell my dev-host's python that I am building a cross-compiled module beyond the env-vars that I am already setting?

Comment: @barnert: Thanks for the update and link, but after studying that blog, I think I'm already closer to a solution with my above update, not to mention the need to untangle the muddle environment from that recipe.  Any other ideas? ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
python ./setup.py build
```

We are trying to cross build an extension, but system uses `python-config` and wrong `pyconfig.h`. See the [difference between](https://gist.github.com/andrew-aladev/6233396d86218f36a7ee439e505f4fb3) `x86_64` and `arm` `pyconfig`. Do not try to use `i686` container to fix `LONG_BIT` issue, this is the wrong way, you will receive more complex issues later.

There are several python extensions that creates virtual env for `python-config`. But there is one 100% reliable way without any extension.

1. Create `amd64` container and install base system (buildah or docker).
2. Install target toolchain into this container (crossdev).
3. Install all required software except python extensions inside target root folder using target toolchain.
4. Add patch for container's python that forces `python-config` to return target [include and library pathes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/sysconfig.py#L27-L30) and rebuild container's python.
5. Install all required python extensions using target toolchain into target root folder.
6. Extract target root folder from container and remove it.